# What represent this pharo classes icons?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I'm seeing different icons for different classes, like in this picture:

[image: Browser pane]

What does it mean? Some of them, with a red icon let me add comments, but the ones with a "c" and a "ray" for example, dont allow me.

The comments mention something about Class Responsibility Collaborator (CRC) design, but it is not clear how comments affect the icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the exclamation mark shows that class has no comment. Lightning is for Exception classes, text bubbles for Announcement. Icons with braces are for collections and the ones with capital sigma (**Σ**) are for magnitude classes (e.g. numbers).

Icons with **C** are for generic classes, icons with **T** are for traits.

There are also classes with a small gray/green/red circle. They show that methods of this class have a test associated with them, and can show if all test pass (green) or not (red). Clicking on an icon like this will run all the tests associates with class's methods